# Having a hard time keeping a rosemary herb alive

Tags: herbs

I have a small rosemary herb that I bought at a grocery store. When I bought it, it was healthy and vibrant but since then it has been a struggle to keep it alive. I mist it, keep it in sunlight and give it water frequently, but it just keeps withering and even the live leaves are thin and emaciated. What should I be doing?

Comment: You are overwatering and misting a desert plant.

Comment: Difficult to get enough light inside for rosemary.

Answer (score 2):

I've *never* misted mine and it's doing fine with south windowsill light and regular watering - sometimes in summer outside, too. Got a couple of years on it. I should probably consider repotting it, I guess.

Its parent (it's a rooted cutting) was doing fine but may have run afoul of either a mite infestation or too much time in the same pot. It withered away in the course of a few weeks after at least 3 years of growing fine with similar care. Fortunately they are in different locations. You might want to look (perhaps with a magnifying glass) for mites and/or webbing.